# Which material should I use to print a mounting adapter for the y-carriage?

Tags: heated-bed, y-axis, linear-motion, carriage

I have purchased a replacement bed for my 3D printer. I wish to have it mounted on a single linear rail.

Currently I am unable to drill properly into aluminum (due to problems with my drill).

Therefore, I'd like to print and use an adapter piece/plate to fasten the Y-carriage to the linear rail block. The bed has a thermal insulation foam so the area around the bottom of the Y-carriage plate/bed assembly doesn't seem to go over 60 °C.

My question is:

- Which material should I use for this adapter piece, and why? *(I have access to PLA, PETG and ABS.)*
- Should I use threaded inserts or fasten the Y-carriage with nuts?

Please see the image below to have an idea as to what I mean by an adapter.

[image]

Comment: What is a heated insert? Are you talking about something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/initeq-M3-0-5-Threaded-Inserts-Printing/dp/B077CKDDVY/ref=asc_df_B077CKDDVY/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=242048563613&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=1092820601930732420&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9032929&hvtargid=pla-409533404050&psc=1)?

Comment: Yes I am @Rykara

Comment: Borrow a drill from someone else. Printing a mounting plate like that would be a terrible idea due to the limited stiffness of plastic, especially at above ambient temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

Any thermoplastic is a bad choice to carry a heated bed. For an **unheated** bed, monolithic (cast, not printed) acrylic plate of sufficient thickness can be used.

To get the needed stiffness and temperature resistance, steel plate of about 2+mm is the best choice, followed by aluminium of a higher thickness. The latter can be sawed with woodworking equipment, if done slowly.